# How to append the word count at the end of 10 digit number in unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I need to display the line count of the file at the end of the file as a trailer. 
I have `0000000000` (10 0's) , so if the line count is `2` then the string should be `0000000002`, if the number of lines in the file are `120` then string should be `0000000120`. I need to display this string at the end of the file as a trailer. Please help how this can be done in unix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try awk

`awk '{print}END{printf("%010i\n", NR)}' file`

Comment: Why does this needs `gnu awk`?  Works fine on my old `busybox awk`

Comment: your busybox awk is probably gawk too.

Comment: But what in this line does it need `gnu awk`? `awk` does have `printf`, `i` option and `NR`.

Comment: Yes gnu-awk not needed, it works on my BSD awk also.

Comment: Or a little bit shorter: `awk '1;END{printf("%010i\n", NR)}' file`

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
printf "%010d" $(wc -l < file.txt) >> file.txt
```

Comment: `$(wc -l file.txt | cut -d" " -f1)` can be simplified by just `$(wc -l < file.txt)`

Comment: 0000000000 should be 10 and lets suppose file count is 111 then last 3  0's should be replaced bt 111 total value would be -> 0000000111 so string remains of 10 char's. In above example string is exceeding 10 chars and it is not actually replacing the 0's instead adding into it.

Comment: Sorry I was still editing my answer. The current version should work.

Comment: @RobinHsu Thanks, this is much cleaner, updating my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `sed` onliner can do the task.

```
sed "$ s/$/\n0000000000$(wc -l < input)/" input
```

**Test**

```
$ cat test

hello
world
how
are
you

$  sed "$ s/$/\n0000000000$(wc -l < test)/" test

hello
world
how
are
you
00000000005
```

**What it does??**

- `$` matches the last line in the file
- `s/$/\n0000000000$(wc -l < input)/"` subtitute, `s` the end of line, `$` in the last line with `0000000000$(wc -l < input)`

**Note**

You can use `-i` option in sed to edit the file inplace so that the change is made in the original file

```
$ sed -i "$ s/$/\n0000000000$(wc -l < test)/" test
$ cat test
hello
world
how
are
you
00000000005
```