# Count how many rows are in one file with defined length to show

Tags: bash, perl, awk, wc

I want to count how many rows are in one file with defined length to show.

In normal case example:

file:

```
2423
546
74868
```

`cat file|wc -l` will show the result: `3`.

But I want to defined length of the numbers for example to have 10 symbols and to show:

```
0000000003
```

if there are 100 lines to be:

```
0000000100
```

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26902438/how-to-append-the-word-count-at-the-end-of-10-digit-number-in-unix/26903103#26903103

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you want something like this:

```
printf '%010d' $(wc -l < file)
```

The format specifier `%010d` means print 10 digits, padded with leading 0s.

As a bonus, in using `<` to pass the contents of the file via standard input, I have saved you a "useless use of `cat`" :)

If I understand your comment correctly, you can do something like this:

```
printf 'Count: %010d' $(( $(wc -l < file) + 1 ))
```

Here I have added some additional text to the format specifier and used an arithmetic context `$(( ))` to add one to the value of the line count.

Comment: Is there anyway to add count to the whole result and to sum +1 ?

Comment: @KalinBorisov you can maybe do `printf '%010d\n' $(( $(wc -l < file) + 1 ))`.

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -ne '}{ printf("%010d\n", $.)' file
```

Reference to [counting lines](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod#Eskimo_greeting) in perl.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'END{printf("%010d\n",NR)}' file
```

Comment: Note that this `awk` approach is way more slow than the `wc` option, I guess because `wc` is more optimized as it is *the* tool for this work. I just compared doing `seq 10000000 > a` and then counting with both methods. `wc` was 7 times faster! Of course, the time was almost negligible, just compared for fun.

Comment: @fedorqui did your timing include formatting the digits output by wc using printf or similar? I found the timings to be about 1:3 rather than 1:7 when I compared the awk solution to `printf "%010d\n" $(wc -l < a)`. As you would expect, of course, wc is faster since it's not trying to split lines into fields and populating builtin variables for each line.

Comment: @EdMorton no, I just compared `wc -l <file` with `time awk 'END{print NR}' file`. My output: `wc --> real 0m0.052s user 0m0.039s sys 0m0.013s` and `awk --> real 0m0.373s user 0m0.366s sys 0m0.005s`.